# Spliting on every character except for preserved substring

Tags: python, regex, string, preserve

Given the string

```
word = "These"
```

that contains the tuple

```
pair = ("h", "e")
```

the aim is to replace the `word` such that it splits on all character except for the `pair` tuple, i.e. output:

```
('T', 'he', 's', 'e')
```

I've tried:

```
word = 'These'
pair = ('h', 'e')
first, second = pair
pair_str = ''.join(pair)
pair_str = pair_str.replace('\\','\\\\')
pattern = re.compile(r'(?<!\S)' + re.escape(first + ' ' + second) + r'(?!\S)')
new_word = ' '.join(word)
new_word = pattern.sub(pair_str, new_word)
result = tuple(new_word.split())
```

Note that sometimes the `pair` tuple can contain slashes, backslashes or any other escape characters, thus the replace and escape in the above regex.

**Is there a simpler way to achieve the same string replacement?**

---

## EDITED

Specifics from comments:

> And is there a distinction between when both characters in the pair are unique and when they aren't?

Nope, they should be treated the same way.

Comment: You don't need to do `pair_str.replace('\\','\\\\')` since `re.escape` will do that.

Comment: What are `first` and `second`?

Comment: Note, I'm using `from __future__ import unicode_literals`.

Comment: If the code works and you're asking for advice on how to redesign it, CodeReview.stackexchange.com is the appropriate place. SO is for help fixing code that doesn't work at all.

Comment: Why would it be `['T', 'he', 's', 'e', 'aa']`? The pair is only `('h', 'e')`, so it should be `['T', 'he', 's', 'e', 'a', 'a']`

Comment: Does the order of the pair matter?

Comment: Yes. I would think the problem comes when the string is `theeeee` and the pair is `('e', 'e')` but when that happens, it should be `('t', 'h', 'ee', 'ee', 'e')`.

Comment: Consecutive runs of preserved characters should be split into groups of 1 or 2? At this point, you may want to add that into a new question, as it invalidates an existing answer.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by *"Consecutive runs of preserved characters should be split into groups of 1 or 2?"*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Match instead of splitting:

```
pattern = re.escape(''.join(pair)) + '|.'
result = tuple(re.findall(pattern, word))
```

The pattern is `<pair>|.`, which matches the pair if possible and a single character* otherwise.

You can also do this without regular expressions:

```
import itertools

non_pairs = word.split(''.join(pair))
result = [(''.join(pair),)] * (2 * len(non_pairs) - 1)
result[::2] = non_pairs
result = tuple(itertools.chain(*result))
```

<sup>* It doesn’t match newlines, though; if you have those, pass `re.DOTALL` as a third argument to `re.findall`.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without using regular expressions:

```
import functools

word = 'These here when she'
pair = ('h', 'e')
digram = ''.join(pair)
parts = map(list, word.split(digram))
lex = lambda pre,post: post if pre is None else pre+[digram]+post

print(functools.reduce(lex, parts, None))
```